# Set up email for a customer.details to get from them

Tags: asp.net, email, smtp, exchange-server

This could be a question related to my area, but I dont know where to ask. There will be a page in our customers website. When they come to that page it will be populated with many email addresses.There will also be an attachment of type PDF. And some email content.They have exchange set up. I know very little about this emailing.Some reason always found it confusing. I need to get some details(email settings) from them for this page to work. Also the email addresses that the page will populate **WILL** contain other than their own domain address.i.e. gmails,msns or yahoos etc. So what is that I need from them?More questions coming. If you need more info,please ask. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using EWS Managed API to communicate with the Exchange server. It's really not that difficult to use once you get your connection established. All you need from them is there credentials for their mailbox, or you could set up a service account with impersonation if you don't want to use theirs.

Here are some resources to get you started:

- [Download the EWS Managed API](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42022)
- [Read conceptual content and 'How To' topics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj536567%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx)
- [See how it's done by downloading sample code](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Exchange-2013-101-Code-3c38582c)

The sample code shows how to authenticate with Exchange, send emails, and a whole lot more. The Exchange developer documentation team continues to post new 'How to' topics.